# Submitted conference paper with errors a short while back. How do I solve this?

Tags: publications, graduate-school, conference, engineering

BACKGROUND
I'm an electrical engineering graduate student.  I submitted and abstract to a conference and it was accepted.  This happened about 3-4 months ago.  Since then, I have mainly focused on other unrelated work.

CURRENT
The paper deadline approached and I submitted the paper.  About 10 days later, I realized there were a few errors.  These errors include plots which were left in the paper that I intended to replace with updated accurate plots.   So I submitted the paper with errors.

QUESTIONS
What do you recommend I do? Will this negatively effect my reputation with the conference?  How big of a problem is this?  My advisor was not happy with me for barely submitting this on time - so this mistake further complicates my problems.

Thanks

Comment: _What do you recommend I do?_ — Correct the errors in your talk, and be more careful next time.

Comment: Depends on how serious the _errors_ are. For ex. do they make your results invalid or factually inaccurate? However if for ex. you simply have new results that indicate that your techniques are more/less accurate by an additional 5%, then probably you should just sit tight and maybe follow JeffE's advice. Finally, also consider the impact this will have downstream. What happens if others in this field of research start building on top of these results of yours that you say contain _errors_?

Comment: Is this archival (as in, is going to be in a conference proceedings)? If not, follow @JeffE's advice. Otherwise, you need to contact the organizers and get it fixed.

Comment: Is the paper already accepted? If it hasn't, or even if the programme has not been finalised, you could send a corrected version to the editor handling the paper.